# Copy and pasting a cell for the next two cells down a column

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a working macro that copies and pastes a cell for the next two rows. However, I need this to work If I have multiple rows of data inputted. I can't figure out the correct code. I also want to add "0", "1", and "2" to the end of each iteration. See below for what I ideally would like.

```
facctnum    facctsname  facctlname  macctnum     
    JW30982250
JW30982251
JW30982252
```

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim cell As Range
Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("B2:" & "B" & Lastrow)
If cell.Value <> "" Then Range("B2:" & "B" & Lastrow).Copy
Range("B3:B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
End Sub
```

For every cell in column B of my spreadsheet I want to paste it twice below itself and then add a "0" to the end of the first cell, "1" to the end of the 2nd cell repetition and a "3" next to the 3rd repetition.

Comment: `For Each cell`... this will loop through `B2`, copying to `B3` and `B4`, then `B3`, copying to `B4` and `B5`, and so on. Do you just want to work with `B2`, `B5`, `B8` and so on?

Comment: I will initially be getting different values on lines B2 to maybe B10. I then want each one of those different values to be copied twice below themselves. so i go from having (123, 555, 777) on each row in col b to having (123, 123, 123, 555, 555, 555, 777, 777, 777)  and adding a "0", "1", and "2". so eventually i have (1230, 1231,1232, 5550, 5551, 5552 etc etc.) Hope this clears up my question a little more

Comment: Yes it does clarify - you'll have to insert cells then. Also, loop from the bottom up.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there an easy code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, looping from the bottom up and inserting an additional two cells with each iteration.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        Range("B" & i).Offset(1).Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("B" & i).Offset(2).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "2"
        Range("B" & i).Offset(1).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "1"
        Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "0"
    Next i
End Sub
```